# Bayesian MLPs using the MCMC methods - any tricks of the trade?

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian, classification, neural-networks

Having used the NETLAB library for MATLAB to implement Bayesian Multi-Layer Perceptron (MLP) neural networks using MacKay's evidence framework, I am now experimenting with Markov Chain Monte Carlo (MCMC) methods using metrop() and hmc().  Does anyone have any advice for successful modelling using this approach (preferably using NETLAB), e.g. how to set the parameters to get good mixing and acceptably low rejection ratios etc?

Has anybody used the Metrpolois-Hastings or HMC samplers for applications of MLP neural networks?  I'm beginning to think that perhaps everybody just uses the evidence framework!

Comment: Do you know about Stan?

Comment: @probability is logic, no, is there a MATLAB interfacte for it (I need to keep everything within MATLAB for consistency and replicability).

Comment: Stan was originally written in matlab, so it should be available (see [here](http://andrewgelman.com/2011/11/30/stan-uses-nuts/) where one complaint was that stan was only available in matlab)   I don't know how matlab works - perhaps there is a stan package or add-on or something.

Answer (score 1):

I have no experience relating to Bayesian Neural Nets and HMC, but with a related task.

That involved using neural nets as an unormalized probability model (i.e. an energy based model) where training involved generating "contrastive/negative samples" from the model distribution via HMC. I suppose the problem is somewhat similar, since both models share some factors.

(More specifically, ${\partial y \over \partial w}$ where $w$ is the first layer's weights and $y$ the output of the net. Bayesian neural nets have a $\partial L / \partial y$ in front, EBMs a different $\partial E / \partial y$ in front and a $\partial w / \partial  x = w$ at the end.)

Long story short: to get decent results using adaptive step rates to reach a desired acceptance rate was making a huge difference.

You can find some code [here](https://github.com/breze-no-salt/breze/blob/master/breze/learn/sampling/hmc.py#L91), but it is python. The approach is described in ["Learning Deep Energy Models", Ngiam et al](http://ai.stanford.edu/~ang/papers/icml11-DeepEnergyModels.pdf) and there is a footnote on the exact settings for HMC.

Comment: THanks for the answer, I'll definitely look into adaptive step size thing, although I would prefer advice on getting the standard Metropolis-Hastings and HMC samplers to work.

Comment: In case you gather enough experience on this to answer your own question I would really appreciate. This is one of the classic areas where research papers do not explain the important details. (Also, thanks for the bounty :)

Comment: You're welcome ;o)  Will do, the main reason why I was asking is that I am working on a method that ought to make the MCMC approach easier, but I don't want to compare against a straw man, so I needed advice on best practice.  The response to the question suggests that perhaps people just don't use it at all, perhaps due to it still being a bit of a "black art".

Answer (score 1):

Radford Neal's flexible Bayesian modeling toolkit (fbm) also allows you to play with the Monte Carlo methods and has neural network functionality built in.